# Using John the Ripper to crack SHA hash w/ partial knowledge

Tags: passwords, hash, sha

Group, I have a SHA1 hash that I would like to brute-force. I have knowledge of several characters before and after the password (ie, if the hash is derived from "xxxpasswordyyy", I know both xxx and yyy).  I'd like to somehow input the xxx and yyy values as constants, so that they are always included in the crack attempt but the "password" portion is brute-forced.

Any examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [wordlist rules documentation](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/RULES.shtml). Based on this, you'd add a line to your rules that read `A0"prefixed_text"Az"postfixed_text"`. Refer to [KoreLogic's rules info](http://contest-2010.korelogic.com/rules.html) for more examples of configuration lines and the format to specify the rule in. You can either add it to a set of existing rules you're already using or specify a new ruleset and use just that.